# How to ignore the condition that user did not pass in SQLITE?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I am doing my crm project with SQLITE+FLASK. And I need a feature is let user to input the condition to filer the result.

I hope that my SQL statement can ignore the WHERE condition if the parameter is space or null.

For example, My input is "NAME", "AGE", "GENDER"
so my statement will be

```
SELECT *
FROM CUSTOMER
WHERE NAME = 'James' AND AGE = '25' AND GENDER = 'M'
```

But I hope that if user did not enter "NAME" my SQL statement can be something like the code below

```
SELECT *
FROM CUSTOMER
WHERE AGE = '25' AND GENDER = 'M'
```

I know maybe I can do this with string concat, but I hope I can do this by SQL statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the `OR` operator for each of the columns, by checking also if the parameter value that you pass is `NULL` or a string with spaces:

```
SELECT *
FROM CUSTOMER
WHERE (NAME = :name OR TRIM(COALESCE(:name, '')) = '')
  AND (AGE = :age OR TRIM(COALESCE(:age, '')) = '')
  AND (GENDER = :gender OR TRIM(COALESCE(:gender, '')) = '')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use null condition as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM CUSTOMER
WHERE (NAME = :name_input or :name_input is null)
  AND (AGE = :age_input or :age_input is null)
  AND (GENDER = :gender_input or :gender_input is null)
```